# Navigation from obj-c to swift file takes too much time for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I import https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell (swift project) into my objective c code. And I do the code for navigation from obj-c to swift using story board.

In `viewController.m`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MainTableViewController* controller;

_controller = [[MainTableViewController alloc]init];

[self Navigation:_controller:@"MainTableViewController"];
```

It works fine, But navigation taking too much time for the first time.
There is no much data to load in Swift file.

Why it takes time for navigation for first time only?